# Bootstrap Textbox and Button Placement Within Row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, textbox, row

I have some basic bootstrap and HTML code that I am trying to plug into an application. My code below places the text box on one row but then has the button and ActionLink directly under the text box. I am attempting to put all 3 of these features on one row across the page.

It is as if the page is columned off and the text box is programmed to take up 100% of the first column width. I can try to change that but would prefer the text box to stay at its current width.

Please note: I attempted to put the button directly next to the text box but it is still getting pushed under it, which is why I think the page is columned off and the textbox is taking up 100% of the first column.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Person", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-actions no-color col-md-12">
            <p>
                Find by name: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="searchString" value="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </p>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
}

New Code:
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtSearch">Find by name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" display="inline-block" id="txtSearch" name="searchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> | 
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</form> <br />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

create an [inline form with bootstrap classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), edited out the razor code, you'll have to put that back in

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtSearch">Find by name:</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="searchString" /> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
    <a href="#"> Back To List </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is starting to get me there. I took out the razor code and edited my code above. It still seems as if the form is columned off for some reason. The button and link are now aligned, but the vertical bar is oddly being pushed under the entire row.

Comment: @AndrewC10 not sure, you may have some other styles conflicting with this code, i would inspect it with something like chrome dev tools. [Check out this jsbin, works fine with no other code interfering](https://jsbin.com/najuvixano/edit?html,output) if you could add a screenshot of what it's doing it may help

Comment: Yes, I feel as if there is CSS overriding what I am attempting to do. I am still learning the full file structure of MVC apps. Attempting to add a screenshot now.

Comment: Just added the pic

Comment: @AndrewC10 lol yeah you probably have some styles messing with it, if youre using chrome right click on the line and then click "inspect element" and uncheck styles until it works, then you've found your culprit. You probably have something like `display:block` set

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class "form-control" of your fisrt input text. Its display is block.  If you want to stay the width of the text. Set the display to inline-block and set the width.